# Restructuring `struct` with generic types for binding with PyO3

Tags: python, rust, types

If I have used generics in a rust implementation such as the following MWE:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<T> {
    a: T,
}

impl<T> A<T> {
    fn new(a: T) -> A::<T> {
        A {a}
    }
}
```

This works fine but if I now want to add Python bindings with PyO3 this wont work because it needs definitive types. If `A` is designed to work with multiple types do I need to re-write all of this (and there will be many more implemented methods) for each specific type when wanting to use the `pyclass` and `pymethods` flags?

```rust
#[pyclass]
struct AF64{
    a: f64,
};

#[pymethods]
impl AF64 {
    #[new]
    fn new(a: f64) -> AF64{
        AF64{ a }
    }
}
```

etc. for `f32`, `i32` etc.. ?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2d25264e572715e35647d36b31fd2dae

Comment: Yes, By definition pyo3 can't expose generic methods since they have to be compiled in on a by-need basis, something pyo3 can not do as the python-side callsites are completely runtime driven. What you can do is define your manual instances as trivial wrappers and delegate to the generic implementation though.

Comment: Also not sure there's much of a point to implement for every number type since Python pretty much only has f64 and infinite precision integers (with IIRC an i32 optimisation).

Comment: @Masklinn intergers and floats are not my issue. This was minimalist by design to illustrate the issue. Thanks for your comment could you perhaps demonstrate a simple trivial wrapper if A<T> had implemented a lot more functions?

Comment: You can always have a macro to declare `ASomething` that wraps `A<Something>`.